# por que no funciona else if?

Tags: c++, condiciones

estoy haciendo un programa que me diga el tipo de triangulo que se forma, todo el codigo esta bien, pero no detecta el `else if` porque aunque se cumpla la condicion que tiene ahi no me aparece el mensaje en la pantalla, en su lugar me aparece siempre lo que esta en `else`.

```
   if(theta>90||alpha>90||beta>90)
   cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es obtusangulo ";
   else if(alpha==90 || theta==90 || beta==90)
   cout<<  "\n\t El triangulo es rectangulo ";
   else 
   cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es acutangulo ";
 return 0;
```

esta es la ultima parte del codigo lo demas funciona, se cumple  `if` y `else`, pero el programa no detecta la condicion de `else if` se pasa de una vez a la ultima condicion, que es lo que esta mal?

Comment: Sería bueno tener el código completo y los valores con los que haz hecho la prueba ya que si es una condición y no entra entonces simplemente puede ser porque no cumple

Comment: muy bien, aca esta el codigo completo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KEj90Oq66LqqSj6f

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Difícilmente alguien se tomará la molestia de visitar un enlace externo y tratar de localizar allí el problema. ¿ Te has pasado por lo que es un [mcve] ? Cuando yo tengo un problema, intento darle todas las facilidades del mundo a aquel que intenta ayudarme.

Comment: Como sugerencia te puedo decir que verifiques que el tipo de dato de tus variables concuerden con el tipo de dato del valor de la comparación... Si usas double deberías comparar con valores doubles también